# how to get svg element type

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

i have a question, how can i get the type of svg element, btw i use d3.js

i have sth like this

```
var selectedElement = svg.select("." + STYLE.selected);

         if (selectedElement instanceof SVGCircleElement){
            alert("here circle");
            selectedElement.style("fill", function(){return d3.rgb(d3.select(this).attr("fill"));});
         }
           if (selectedElement instanceof SVGPathElement){
             alert("here path");
                appendMarkerm(selectedElement,false);

         }
```

but it seems didnt work , can someone help out here ,thanks !!

---

```
***finally, i made it work like this*** 

var selectedElement = svg.select("." + STYLE.selected);
           if (selectedElement.node() instanceof SVGCircleElement){
            selectedElement.style("fill", function(){return d3.rgb(d3.select(this).attr("fill"));});
         }
           if (selectedElement.node() instanceof SVGPathElement){
            changeMarkerStyle(selectedElement,false); 
         }
```

cauz selection.node() will return the first element of the selection

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName) property:

```
svg.select("." + STYLE.selected)
   .call( function(){

      switch( selectedElement.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
        case 'circle': 
          alert("here circle");
          this.style("fill", function(){return d3.rgb(d3.select(this).attr("fill"));});
          break;

        case 'path':
          alert("here path");
          appendMarkerm( this, false );
          break;
      }

    });
```

**EDIT**

d3js' [`select()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select) does not return the element itself, but a d3js wrapper for it (very much like in jQuery, e.g.). So the easiest way, would be to use the [`call()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-call) method to apply a function to all matches (in the case of just [`select()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select) this is just one).

Comment: hi sirko, i tried ur way, but it didn't work, selectedElement.tagName is undefined , this is weird

Comment: @user2717621 What library are you using and what doesn `svg.select` actually return?

Comment: svg.select returns an objet of SVGCircleElement or SVGPathElement,i use D3.js